# Why does compiler select a general overload than a specific overload?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, overloading, overload-resolution

Here is the thing, I have two overloads for a method which accepts `IDictionary<T,K>` and `IEnumerable<T>`. Now for the most part almost always the compiler selects appropriate overload when called on an object.

But sometimes when the Dictionary becomes a bit complex like,

`IReadOnlyDictionary<CustomClassA<CustomClassB>, IOrderedEnumerable<CustomClassC<CustomClassD>>>` the compiler just selects overload for `IEnumerable<T>`, maybe because it is more simpler.

I do know that explicitly casting the object to Dictionary time might resolve the issue, however do note that these overloads also recursive like if `Dictionary<List<int>> obj` is there then calling overloaded method will execute and when found List it will go to the other overload also.

Also, IOrderedEnumerable overload is implemented.

Comment: `IReadOnlyDictionary` does not inherit from `IDictionary`, but does inherit from `IEnumerable`

Comment: Agreed, however when I try to implement overload for `IReadOnlyDictionary`, anything in the form of `KeyValuePair` points to the `IReadOnlyDictionary` and none towards `IDictionary`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a [mcve] that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation on overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution)?

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue - if I have an overload for `IReadOnlyDictionary` than an argument of type `IReadOnlyDictionary` picks that overload. What does "in the form of `KeyValuePair`" mean exactly?